# C1 CMS - Restore the CSS file

Tags: css, content-management-system, restore, composite

I've made changes in the css file that defines the whole style for the website and saved these changes. Unfortunately, as I am not a web designer, I don't have the previous version of style.css. Is there any opportunity to cancel the implemented changes or restore the previous version of the file?

Comment: Have you already deployed your changes to production?

Comment: If your code is maintained via any versioning systems like git,svn. You can get back to old state by reverting your previous commit/push

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately you can't if you have already saved and deployed your code or your code is not maintained via any version controlling systems like git.

What i can suggest by looking at your situation is if you are looking for fresh file from the c1 CMS you should install again in a different folder and then go to "~/Frontend/Styles/" folder of your new project and look for styles.min.css file. Other than that sorry you can't.

Thanks, Hope this helps.